# Problems with Codeigniter and MY_Upload class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem while using Codeigniter and the class for multiple upload files named MY_upload.

I have this code that it's not working at all, I see a blank page.

```
    class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('MY_Upload');
        }
    function do_upload_multiple($file)
    {


        $this->upload->initialize(array(
                 "upload_path"   => "./uploads/"
            ));

            //Perform upload.
            if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("files"){
                $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
```

If I remove the function do_upload_multiple and just $this->load->library('MY_upload'); It doesn't work either. It's like the library doesn't load, make some kind of error but Codeigniter doesn't displays it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to load MY_Upload as its own library unless MY_Upload isn't extending the existing upload library. The point of using MY_ (or custom set) prefixes in classes is to extend the functionality of existing classes in CI.

Comment: Oh, I get it. So as I don't have to load the library, Can I use the methods for MY_* class just by loading the existent class in CI? In this example, can I call $this->upload->initialize(); just like other method from the Upload class? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Exactly. What you just described :)